# URL Image not displayin View Razor ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload image from website for example.
foo.company.com/image1.png, the image in the explorer opens, but when placing in the view the error appears:

"Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

```
<img src="http://foo.company.com/image1.png" height="80">
```

The weird thing is that I have another project in ASP.NET 4.5 and the image loads without problems. Do you have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you try to delete height="80",can it work?Maybe it is blocked by ad blocker.

Comment: ok! i'm delete height=80 y continue error.

Comment: Which browser you get the error?